# Access Google API key through OAuth

Tags: api, oauth

I'd like to use my user's Google API Key for API requests made in my app on their behalf.  Is this possible using the Google OAuth API?

Answer (score 0):

No. OAuth uses your APIKey to access the data, the user provides permission.

http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/articles/oauth.html#Registration

If you want them to access many different API's then you write your app/website to do that and Google will ask the user the first time your application tries to access it.